# Why do we want the no error limit to be 1?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory

In a textbook by Nielsen and Chuang, there's the following paragraph:

> The idea of quantum data compression is that the compressed data should be recovered with very good fidelity. Think of the fidelity as being analogous to the probability of doing the decompression correctly – in the limit of large block lengths, it should tend towards the no error limit of 1.

If there isn't/very minimum error, shouldn't the no error limit be 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Perhaps you need to review the defintion of fidelity. It's sort of an upside down trace distance so achieving a fidelity of 1 is usually the goal

Comment: I think he's just doesn't understand that the ''limit of 1'' is actually referred to that the fidelity is 1. Intuitively misunderstanding the no error is actually 0 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per N&C, fidelity is "analogous to the probability of doing the decompression **correctly**" (emphasis added). The goal is to do the operation correctly with 100% probability, which means the probability is 1. This is the desired limit of fidelity, so no error means the fidelity is 1.